# Why doesn't curl work using an IPv6 connection?

Tags: ipv6

How come a:

```
curl -v -6 http://badurl.com
```

doesn't work but a:

```
curl -v -6 --head http://badurl.com
```

Perfectly works?

MTU isn't the problem (?) since:

```
root@server:~# ping6 -c 10 -s 2000 -M do IPV6ADDRESSOFBADURL.COM
PING IPV6ADDRESSOFBADURL.COM(IPV6ADDRESSOFBADURL.COM)
2000 data bytes From IPV6ADDRESSOFSOMEGATEWAY icmp_seq=1 Packet too big: mtu=1452
2008 bytes from IPV6ADDRESSOFBADURL.COM: icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=82.5 ms
2008 bytes from IPV6ADDRESSOFBADURL.COM: icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=82.4 ms
```

tcpdump shows that if the IPv6 connection is bad then my Desktop doesn't receives anything..ip6tables is empty.

**My question**: WHY does the connection "randomly gets bad" from my Desktop machine that has native IPv6 address to IPv6 enabled websites? (problem occurs not just on one site)

Or any hints, how to debug this?

Comment: badurl.com doesn't have an IPv6 address.

Comment: Clarify "doesn't work"?  Have you used `tcpdump` to watch the packets to see *where* it's failing?  This looks entirely like a PMTU issue.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that MTU isn't part of the problem?

"2000 data bytes From IPV6ADDRESSOFSOMEGATEWAY icmp_seq=1 Packet too big: mtu=1452"

IPv6 routers will *not* fragment any packets, connections rely on PMTU and if any is too big for any hop in the path, it's simply discarded and an ICMPv6 Packet Too Big is sent back.